# jQuery Delay and Queue not always running after window.onhashchange

Tags: jquery

This code seems to work perfectly:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    if (!window.location.href.match('#pop')) {
        //alert('go back last');
        $('#main').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.pop').removeClass('pop-ready');
        $('.pop').addClass('pop-hidden');
    }

    /* navigate back after back button */
    if (!window.location.href.match('#secondpage')) {
        $('#pageCont').removeClass('posTwo');
        $('#pageOne').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#pageTwoInner').addClass('hidden'); 

    }
    if (window.location.href.match('#secondpage')) {
        $('#pageCont').addClass('posTwo');

        $('#pageTwoInner').removeClass('hidden'); 
    }
};
```

However when I when I add a delay and queue to one function the code becomes temperamental and sometimes that class is not added:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    if (!window.location.href.match('#pop')) {
        //alert('go back last');
        $('#main').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.pop').removeClass('pop-ready');
        $('.pop').addClass('pop-hidden');
    }

    /* navigate back after back button */
    if (!window.location.href.match('#secondpage')) {
        $('#pageCont').removeClass('posTwo');
        $('#pageOne').removeClass('hidden');
                    /* CHANGE HERE */
        $('#pageTwoInner').delay(200).queue(function(){
            $(this).addClass('hidden'); 
        });
    }
    if (window.location.href.match('#secondpage')) {
        $('#pageCont').addClass('posTwo');

        $('#pageTwoInner').removeClass('hidden'); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), you have to dequeue the next item or the callback chain will be broken.

There are two ways to achieve this. Either call [dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) from your callback:

```
$("#pageTwoInner").delay(200).queue(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden").dequeue(); 
});
```

Or call the `next` argument passed to your callback:

```
$("#pageTwoInner").delay(200).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass("hidden"); 
    next();
});
```

Comment: your answer is technically valid, but it doesn't appear to explain why the _currently_ queued function isn't running - it would only explain why _subsequent_ queued events don't run.

Comment: @Alnitak, I think that's exactly what is happening here, that's why the the questioner says `the code becomes temperamental and sometimes that class is not added`.

Comment: if the class isn't added it means _this_ function isn't been queued, not that later functions aren't dequeued.